# Unable to install ‘File’ from ionic-native - dependencies related?

Tags: node.js, cordova, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

So I'm pretty fresh in Ionic2 so I'm getting some newbie troubles =/ I've searched pretty much everything and I can't find any examples for this.

What I want to do is to write a file to a certain directory of the device. I'm using Ionic2 and I've seen that there's a '[File API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/)' that does what I need. But the problem is that I can't set it up.

Whenever I do `$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file` I get this output:

```
`project@0.0.1 D:\project\
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0
+-- @ionic-native/file@3.2.1
-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12`

`npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic-native/file@3.2.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic-native/file@3.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ionic-native/file@3.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.1 but none was installed.`
```

But whenever I try to use npm install for these missing dependencies, it keeps giving me the same errors over and over again. I'm quite lost here. I've tried to delete node_modules, cache clean and install and I still can't get the File to work.

If you could assist me here that would be great. I can provide other info if needed. Cheers!

--------- Here are my dependencies from **package.json**

```
`
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "cordova": "^6.5.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "xml2json": "^0.11.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
    "jscs": "^3.0.7",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've fixed this problem.

1: Remove node_modules, clean cache and install all dependencies again

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

2: In my problem, I needed ionic-native@core to be 3.1.0 or higher to be able to use ionic-native@file. So I run

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/core
```

And it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install it in brand new project and npm also complained about @ionic-native/core missing. In fact, you should try to install it (and other dependencies) separately before installing @ionic-native/file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've tried to install the UNMET PEER angular, native and rxjs but it keeps complaining about it =/

Comment: And did it installed successfully? Try to check this with 'npm ls' in your project directory. You can also try to install missing peers in other order

Comment: Good news, I've just fixed the problem. Seems like the version of 'file' that I installed required the ionic-native@core version to be 3.1.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Install all dependencies again

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/core
```